# Prompting a user for two numbers in Unix to make a calculation

Tags: shell, unix, echo

I want to write a script which will prompt the user for two numbers, representing the width and height of a rectangle in centimetres and output the area of the rectangle in both square centimetres and  square inches. In Unix ( one inch = 2.54 centimetres).

I think its something like:

```
echo "Please enter the width:"
read width

echo "Please enter the second height"
read height

ANS=`expr width \* height`
echo "$ANS"
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason to store the output of `expr` in a variable and then echo the variable instead of just letting `expr` write its output?

Comment: to be pedantic, one inch = 2.54 cm not just in Unix

Answer (score 2):

Short one :)

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Width  in cm (default 1)? " w
read -p "Height in cm (default 1)? " h
read acm ain <<<$(dc<<<"5k${w:-1}sa${h:-1}sb2.54silalb*sclcli/li/sdlcps.ldps.q")
echo "width: ${w:-1}(cm), height: ${h:-1}(cm) - Area: $acm (sqcm) $ain (sqin)"
```

**EDIT**: added description

the `dc` is [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) calculator, and doing the next

- set precision to 5
- number $w (if not set 1) store to "a"
- number $h store to "b"
- 2.54 store to i
- take "a" take "b" and multiply result store to "c"
- take "c" take "i" and divide, again take "i" divide again, store the result to "d"
- take "c" and print
- take "d" and print
- quit

in the "normal" math:

```
a=$w; b=$h; i=2.54; c=a*b; d=c/i/i ; print c; print d
```

and the script, the

- `<<<` is the one-line "heredoc" - `dc` will read it as its input from stdin
- `$(commnad)` mean: replace the $(command) with the result of the command
- `read x y <<<` mean read two values into the variable x and y (the `dc` returns 2 values)

Comment: I'm trying to understand, but my effort is as futile as trying to understand an amazonian shaman ritual of summoning the gods of healing. But it's working, so +1. :)

Comment: This is crazy, but +1 for introducing people to shaman rituals ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the shell you are using. [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) has support for floating point arithmetics, other shells don't. In `ksh` you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh

typeset -f width height sq_cm sq_in

printf "Please enter the width in cm:  "; read width
printf "Please enter the height in cm: "; read height

((sq_cm = width * height))
((sq_in = sq_cm / 2.54 / 2.54))

echo "Results:"
printf "%.2f sq cm\n" "${sq_cm}"
printf "%.2f sq in\n" "${sq_in}"
```

Example run:

```
$ ./ksh.sh
Please enter the width in cm:  2.5
Please enter the height in cm: 2.5
Results:
6.25 sq cm
0.97 sq in
```

If you are using e.g. [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), one way is - like Steven pointed out - to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). Another option is `bc`. If you use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), `read` can take care of printing a prompt for you so you can get rid of the superfluous `echo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the width in cm:  " width
read -p "Please enter the height in cm: " height

sq_cm="$(echo "scale=3; ${width} * ${height}" | bc)"
sq_in="$(echo "scale=3; ${sq_cm} / 2.54 / 2.54" | bc)"

echo "Results:"
printf "%.2f sq cm\n" "${sq_cm}"
printf "%.2f sq in\n" "${sq_in}"
```

Example run:

```
$ ./bash.sh
Please enter the width in cm:  2.5
Please enter the height in cm: 2.5
Results:
6.25 sq cm
0.97 sq in
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!awk -f
BEGIN {
  if (ARGC != 3) {
    print "calc.awk WIDTH HEIGHT"
    print "input must be in CM"
    exit
  }
  printf "%s\n%.2f\n%s\n%.2f\n",
    "area square cm",
    ARGV[1] * ARGV[2],
    "area square in",
    ARGV[1] * ARGV[2] / 2.54^2
}
```

[Thanks Greg](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022)